# Empty space in GNUPLOT graph

Tags: gnuplot

I am encountering strange behavior on my gnuplot script. The objective of this script is to read in a file and plot a specific set of lines (3 consecutive lines based on a given start point in the file) using the very first line of the file as the series headers.

While the plot works conceptually, I am encountering a large insert into the image on the left side, as if an empty line is read and plotted as 0 (with no header)

Input File:

```
Level,Filter,Type,Set1,Set2,Set3
Level1,Filter1,Type1,112,186,90
Level1,Filter1,Type2,233,335,159
Level1,Filter1,Type3,224,332,157
```

Code:

```
set terminal postscript color
set output '| epstopdf --filter --outfile=output.pdf'

set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
set style data histograms

set datafile separator "," 

LINE1 = 1 + 3 * COUNT
LINE2 = LINE1 + 1
LINE3 = LINE1 + 2

plot '../test.csv' \
u ( ( int($0) == LINE1 || int($0) == LINE2 || int($0) == LINE3)? $4 : 1/0) ti col,'' \
u ( ( int($0) == LINE1 || int($0) == LINE2 || int($0) == LINE3)? $5 : 1/0) ti col,'' \
u ( ( int($0) == LINE1 || int($0) == LINE2 || int($0) == LINE3)? $6 : 1/0) ti col
```

Command Line Call

```
>gnuplot -e "COUNT=0" test.plot
```

How can I get rid of the empty fields that lead to the right shift?

My gnuplot version is 4.6.

Comment: COUNT is uninitialized, so I'm having a hard time guessing to reproduce this error.

Comment: Also, you have `set datafile separator ","`, but you have no ',' in your datafile.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the question so that it is easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using pipes and unix-ish tools, I would use `sed` here as well:

```
set term post color
set output 'foo.ps'

set style data histograms 
set style histogram clustered 

set datafile separator ","     

set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid

SED_CMD = sprintf('< sed -n -e 1p -e %d,%dp test.csv',COUNT*3+2,COUNT*3+4)

plot for [COL=4:6] SED_CMD u COL ti col
```

I've simplified a lot of things while I was trying to figure out what your script was doing -- I used plot iteration (introduced in gnuplot 4.3).  Originally I had thought that `plot '...' every ...` would work, but histograms seem to choke on `every` and I don't (yet!) understand why.

Here's an explanation of the `sed` command:

```
-e 1p      #print first line in file
-e %d,%dp  #print n'th line through m'th line (inclusive) where n=COUNT*3+2 and m=COUNT*3+4
```

If you're worried about shell injection, this seems to be safe as well:

```
gnuplot -e 'COUNT=";echo hi"' -persist test.gp
"test.gp", line 10: Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected
```

Gnuplot will only write numbers to your command string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mgilson, it seems that there is some problem still. When I run the code i get the following error:

get_data: key title not found in requested column

plot for [COL=4:6] SED_CMD u COL ti col

                                    ^

"test.plot", line 12: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

I tried removing the "ti col" to no avail. The sed command works beautifully on the commandline, so I am not quite sure what is wrong.

Comment: @lichtenj -- Can you post your updated script as an addendum to your question?  I'll keep working on this as long as I have enough information to be able to reproduce your problem :)

Comment: I tried using the script the way you suggested, I added your version to the question.

Comment: @lichtenj -- I was working with your datafile -- the version before you added `','`.  Does adding `set datafile sep ','` help?